# React | Redux | Thunk - How data should be loaded from within a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I've got a component that uses componentWillMount to make an API call through redux to get data and update the state.

Before calling this method, I need to go to the DB and get a property upon which I'll decide if the data retrieval (from the 1st paragraph) should happen.

What I was thinking of doing (using promises) -

1. Fetch the property (from paragraph 2)
2. then, if data is needed, dispatch the normal flow (paragraph 1).
3. if data is not needed, carry on.

My question is WHERE should it go in your opinon.

On the one hand, it feels like a mega overkill to do it through the store. On the other hand, any chance I'll encounter side effect problems. 
In addition, I could implement the logic in the component or in the action creator. What do you think is best?

Additional info: 
1. I'm using redux-thunk. Changing to sagas is out of the question.
2. The property that I'm checking is in 1 reducer, while the data that needs to be fetched is in another reducer (dunno, might be problematic for some solutions.).

**Option 1:**

```
import {getData} from '....../dataActions';
import {getToken} from '......../userActions';

const MegaComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
    getToken(uid)
        .then(shouldUpdate => {
        if (shouldUpdate) {
            getData(uid);
        } else {
            console.log('no need to get data');
        }
      }) 
  }
}

funciton mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
    user: state.user
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
    getToken: (uid) => dispatch(getToken(uid)),
    getData: (uid) => dispatch(getData(uid))
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MegaComponent);
```

**Option 2 (what I think should be done)**

```
export function getToken(uid) {
    return dispatch => {
    return api.getToken(uid)
        .then(token => {
        if (token === 'what it should') {
            return {type: 'NO_DATA_CHANGE_NEEDED', action: null};
        } else {
            // the action that handle getting data is in a different action creator.
            // I either import it here and call it, or there's a better way.
        }
      })
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This might come in handy for future visiotrs - [getting state inside an action creator](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/102)

Answer (score 3):

Hey this is a very broad question, but I want to give a short advice on how I would solve it although I am not quite sure if i got it totally right.

So I would start by separating the concerns of point 1. (database call) and 2. (everything else)

You could start by writing a Component-Wrapper (HoC) that only does the database call to get the prop you need for further processing.

Once you fetched the data from db you can render the InnerComponent with the data as prop and do everything else you need there just by checking the prop you injected and trigger additional actions.

Comment: Interesting approach! might be a solution.
I'll try to add some code to the question.

Comment: hi mate, i've added some code, think it might be helpful

Comment: Yeah, I see that you dispatch getData() if required, but how do you get back the data to your Component? The data is kept in the store? But you don't map that state to props. So even if you change the data, how do you get that updated data to your Component?

Comment: I omitted that part on purpose, tried to make the code a bit easier to read. 
I think I'll implement Option 2 and I will import the otherAction creator and call the getData from within the getToken. 
The getData action is the one that handles the state update you mentioned in your previous comment.
What are your thoughts on my solution?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't let my component deal with logic. keep your components all about View. Think of a component as a visual representation of a point-in-time state.

In `componentWillMount` you can check if the data exists, if it's not then you call your action which will fetch the data through an API and pass the data to the reducer. the reducer will 'update' the state.

the dispatch calls should be invoked from `actions.js` and not from your component.

Answer (score 0):

So, my feeling was right - option 2 it is. Much like @guruPitka suggested.

In my action creator (that is being called by the component), I get the current app state, make an API call, compare the tokens and act accordingly.

```
export function getToken(uid) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const currentToken = getState().user.token;

        return api.lastAppLaunch(uid)
            .then(newToken => {
                if (newToken === currentToken) {
                    // All is good, carry on.
                } else {
                    dispatch(getData(uid)); //getData is from a different action creator.
                }
            });
    }
}
```

And the call in the component -

```
this.props.getToken(uid);
```